# Dispatch redux thunk action in google sign in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am using redux thunk in react and I am unable to dispatch an action from google sign in flow. If I don't use async dispatch then I see the google popup for login but I can't dispatch an action but if I use async dispatch then clicking on the button does nothing. Here is my code:

```js
export const googleSignIn =  () => {
     return async dispatch => {
      try {
        await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
        const { accessToken } = await GoogleSignin.signIn();  
        dispatch({ 
                type: 'SignInSuccess',
                payload: accessToken,
        })
      } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
      }
   }
};
```

**If I call this action then the google sign in popup doesn't open up**.

If I remove async dispatch and make the whole function async then it opens up but in that case how can I dispatch an action?